# java: Read text file and store the info in an array using scanner class

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error, java.util.scanner

I have a text file include Student Grades like:

```
Kim $ 40 $ 45
Jack $ 35 $ 40
```

I'm trying to read this data from the text file and store the information into an array list using Scanner Class.  Could any one guide me to write the code correctly?

#### Code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadStudentsGrade {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ArrayList stuRec = new ArrayList();
    File file = new File("c:\\StudentGrade.txt");
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("$");

        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            String stuName = scanner.nextLine();
            int midTirmGrade = scanner.nextInt();
            int finalGrade = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println(stuName + " " + midTirmGrade + " " + finalGrade);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

#### Runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at writereadstudentsgrade.ReadStudentsGrade.main(ReadStudentsGrade.java:26)
```

Comment: What problems are you having? How does your fail to solve your problem?

Comment: @Amateur: try my answer, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try `useDelimiter(" \\$ |[\\r\\n]+");`

```
        String stuName = scanner.next(); // not nextLine()!
        int midTirmGrade = scanner.nextInt();
        int finalGrade = scanner.nextInt();
```

Your problems were that:

- You mistakenly read *whole line* to get student name
- `$` is a regex metacharacter that needs to be escaped
- You need to provide both line delimiters and field delimiters

Comment: The delimiter is also crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is off.

`nextLine()` will get you all what's left of the line and advance the cursor to there.
`nextInt()` will then jump delimiters until it finds an int.
The result will be skipping of values.
Assuming Kim and Jack were on different lines you would get:

```
stuName == "Kim $ 40 $ 45"
midTirmGrade == 35
finalGrade == 40
```

as your output; which isn't what you want.

Either you need to use the end-of-line as the delimiter or use a [StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to break each line up and then parse each of the sections as individual tokens.