# How to read only the part of data(double) required from a text file in java and put it to double array[]

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I want to read only the first part of the number mentioned under distribution points. That is "-5.344029659372277" and then store all these points into an array in java.

```
Using fixed random seed for repeat ability.
............................................
Constructing inference engine of class blog.engine.SamplingEngine
Constructing sampler of class blog.sample.LWSampler
Evidence: []
Query: [x, y, z]
Running for 20 samples...
Query Reporting interval is 10000
========  LW Trial Stats =========
Log of average likelihood weight (this trial): -4.440892098500626E-16
Average likelihood weight (this trial): 0.9999999999999996
Fraction of consistent worlds (this trial): 1.0
Fraction of consistent worlds (running avg, all trials): 1.0
======== Query Results =========
Number of samples: 20
Distribution of values for x
-5.344029659372277  0.05000000000000003
-3.6282706290477384 0.05000000000000003
-3.497553178865327  0.05000000000000003
-0.8324886197923229 0.05000000000000003
Distribution of values for y
-3.8401834274154405 0.05000000000000003
-2.8617608524112454 0.05000000000000003
-2.8211880095793065 0.05000000000000003
-2.1727081725855695 0.05000000000000003
Distribution of values for z
-3.6803989664398955 0.05000000000000003
-2.3049623281250717 0.05000000000000003
-2.300277789550218  0.05000000000000003
-2.110311642917156  0.05000000000000003 
======== Done ========
```

This is how it looks in the output.txt from the BLOG program.

Comment: Does the above mentioned data have a specific start location/index in the file, which is constant?

Comment: Could you show what you have tried?

Comment: There are 15 lines of text which is common from the start of the text file, then the distribution points start. I am taking the output of a BLOG programming language into a text file and am trying to read it into java program.

Comment: Could you please show the whole file and the code which you have tried?

Comment: Use FileReader and StringTokenizer

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? You know how to use the `Scanner`, right? Read the first 15 lines, throw them out, then keep reading, putting the numbers you read into an array. Have you tried it?

Comment: If you want to skip 15 lines you have to traverse 14 lines. Or if the lines are of equal length use BufferedReader .skip()

Comment: I can skip, but I want only the first number of the distribution, I want to discard the second part. -5.344029659372277  0.05000000000000003... i want only (-5.344029659372277).. into double array

Comment: possible duplicate of [java: Read text file and store the info in an array using scanner class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440103/java-read-text-file-and-store-the-info-in-an-array-using-scanner-class)

Comment: @Balu check my answer please. I think it does want you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example, explanations are in code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    List<String> xValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> yValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> zValues = new ArrayList<String>();
    //convert these lists of String to double yourself.

    xValues = readValuesFor("x");
    yValues = readValuesFor("y");
    zValues = readValuesFor("z");

    //print contents
    System.out.println("X values: ");
    for (final String x : xValues) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    System.out.println("Y values: ");
    for (final String y : yValues) {
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    System.out.println("Z values:");
    for (final String z : zValues) {
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}

public static List<String> readValuesFor(String variableName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("output.txt")); //change file name and path to yours
    String line;
    //read through file until you find a line that end with the variable x ,y, or z
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.endsWith("for "+variableName.trim())) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!variableName.equals("z")) { //if variable is x or y
        while (!(line = br.readLine()).contains("Distribution")) {
            //read the lines between line ending in letters x or y and line containing word "Distribution"
            final String[] values = line.split(" "); 
            result.add(values[0]); //get the first value of the split
        }
    }
    else{
        while (!(line = br.readLine()).contains("Done")) { //if variable is z
            //read the lines between line ending with letter z and line containing word "Done"
            final String[] values = line.split(" ");
            result.add(values[0]); //get the first value of the split
        }
    }
    return result; //array with first values as string
}
```

Output is:

```
X values: 
-5.344029659372277
-3.6282706290477384
-3.497553178865327
-0.8324886197923229
Y values: 
-3.8401834274154405
-2.8617608524112454
-2.8211880095793065
-2.1727081725855695
Z values:
-3.6803989664398955
-2.3049623281250717
-2.300277789550218
-2.110311642917156
```

Comment: the split is not working. am getting both the values